# WSO2 BPS foreach issue

Tags: foreach, wso2, bpel, wso2-business-process

I am trying to do a `forEach`, and inside `forEach` use the counters in a `doXSLTransform` to derive the source. It is working fine if the `forEach` `finalCounter = 1` otherwise i am getting error for passing multiple elements in the `doXSLTransform` source. I checked the Oasis specs for BPEL and it supports passing the counter using the `$`, please advise as I am not sure what is going wrong with WSO2 BPS.

Comment: Add more details about what you tried, what happened and what is actually expected. Some pseudo code will be useful to anyone looking at your question

Comment: sure, I have 3 foreach inside eachother with 2 counters, which are created using startcounter value and finalcounter value. trying to do assign in the inner most foreach with a doXSLTransform taking the 2nd element (source), $output.payload//*[local-name()='activity'][$counter1]/*[local-name()='dp'][$counter2] and I am getting selectionFailure: Multiple results for expression.

Comment: ODE <= 1.3.5 had some issues with counter variables where the value was stored as a float instead of an integer (i.e. 1.0 instead of 1). I'm not sure if this can affect the XPath rule but it is perhaps worth investigating. Maybe a cast or floor() can help.

Comment: I tried round and number and floor, with the three counter variables and it is not working, i even tried doing a variable and incrementnig it by myself and it is still not working if the counter value is >1 please advice I am trying to integrate BPS with BRS and it is not working because of the failure of creating vars.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with round function. Usually, it resolves the problem.

$output.payload//*[local-name()='activity'][round($counter1)]/*[local-name()='dp'][round($cou‌​nter2)]

Answer (score 0):

I tried round and floor, it worked for the do transform but not in the assign xpath expression, it is really strange.